# How can I look up the local computer name in swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying to return a string of the local computer name (as shown in sharing in system preferences).

I have found this method in objective-c but i'm unsure how I can convert this to swift and set a string variable to the returned value.

```
[[NSHost currentHost] localizedName];
```

If anyone could help that would be great!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

edit/update

**Xcode 8 beta • Swift 3**

```
let currentHost = Host.current().localizedName ?? ""
```

---

---

NSHost localizedName property returns an optional String. You can use if let or "??" nil coalescing operator to unwrap the String returned:

```
let currentHost = NSHost.currentHost().localizedName ?? ""
```

Comment: Would you recommend using if let of ?? nil

Comment: @dbus I prefer using ?? you can set a default value or return an empty String as I did in my code

Comment: Thanks i;m using your method.

Comment: Do not use the Swift 3.0 version because it's broken. I just looked up the implementation and it looks like this: `open var localizedName: String? { return nil }` :face palm:

Comment: It is noted there Swift 3 Xcode 8 beta. I haven't tested with Xcode 8 AppStore Version and or 8.1

Comment: Sure thing, but Foundation is out now and the property is unimplemented on the master branch. I just filed a bug.